# Is a generic sql query possible in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

If I have a method to create SQL queries, as below :

```
public List selectTuple() {
   boolean status = true;
   String query = "SELECT ";
   query += getFields() == null ? " * " : " " + getFields() + " ";
   query += " FROM " + tables;
   if ( getSearchClause() != null ) {
       query += " " + getSearchClause();
   }
   query += ";";
   Debug("SQL...........caleed selectTuple method, query is : "+ query);
   setQuery(query);
   if ( getPrepared() ) {//If this is a Prepared query,
      status = setPreparedStatement();
   } else {
      status = setNonPreparedStatement();
   }
   if ( ! status ) {
      Log("[CRITICAL] (.........)..........");
   }
   status = doExecuteQuery();
   if ( ! status ) {
      Log("[CRITICAL] (.........)..........");
   }
   return( getResults() );
}//method selectTuple
```

However, since this will be used for different tables, the fields will be of different data types (int, string, date etc). So how can I iterate through such a ResultSet ?

Also, how can I create such an Insert query ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can, you'll just need to inspect the results to determine the types and build out dynamically.

Comment: methods like this one are the ever living source of SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: Hi Preet, can you pls paste a sample code ?

Comment: If at all possible, use JPA or JPQL and forget about creating your own SQL library.  JDBC is a major drag...

Comment: @Oleg: Why do you think its vulnerable to sql injection ? It can create both a prepared query and a non prepared query.

Comment: Anything that creates SQL queries on the fly is potentially vulnerable. This method relies on the fact that `getFields()` and `tables` and `getFields()` are sterile, and in real life such an assumption could result in your server being wiped out.

Comment: @OlegMikheev but if they are sterile, then it's fine. I agree about being cautious, but sometimes it makes things more difficult with no value added.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it could be done... You can use getMetaData() in the ResultSet to get the number and type of columns and iterate through the ResultSet consequently.

[getMetaData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29):

[ResultSetMetaData class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

However, I don't know how to code such a generic insert query...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [getObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int,%20java.util.Map%29) and pass a map of JDBC to Java object mappings for your own types if any.

So, if your table has column `i` numeric and column `s` varchar the next code

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select i, s from test");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getObject(1).getClass());
System.out.println(rs.getObject(2).getClass());
```

will result in

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.String
```

the only thing for you to do is to check the returned Object for its class, using `instanceof`, to do the actual casting.

You can refer to [this article](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html#1008372) for more details.

For the insert part you could use [setObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method and rely on JDBC conversion, which is probably not a very good idea but should work.

Answer (score 0):

As @jahroy commented, avoid using JDBC for this type of generic things. I also just had the same problem and I came up with an easy and elegant way to do it with [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html)

Here's a generic method I've created to handle any `SELECT` query, you can get the idea how `JPA` works. In this case I just wanted to make sure there were only `SELECT` queries but you can make it more generic, to accept `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`...

```
public List executeSelectQuery(String selectQuery, Class entityClass, String classPersistentUnit)
{
    selectQuery = selectQuery.toUpperCase();
    if(!selectQuery.startsWith("SELECT"))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This method only accepts SELECT queries. You tried: " + selectQuery);
    }

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(classPersistentUnit);
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(selectQuery, entityClass);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The good thing is that Netbeans and Eclipse (and probably more IDEs too, but I just use these two) come up with an "auto-create" class Entity, on the fly! You don't need to code anything at all on these entity classes. An entity class, briefly, represents a table in your database. Therefore each table in your database will be represented by an entity class.

You can find an easy and small tutorial [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native)